# any open source CAdES signature implementation

Tags: java, digital-signature

I want to create an app for digital signature, and the standard seems to be [CAdES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAdES_%28computing%29), could anyone point me to an open source (so it can be customized) implementation with practical examples to follow?

Comment: I mean open source so I can customize it

Comment: Thanks for making that explicit.

Comment: Thanks to you, I have seen Ibkey cades implementation but I can't make it work in development, any experience with this would be appreaciated too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BouncyCastle 1.46b17 has an implementation of CAdES which was provided as a series of patches to the main codebase.

If you examine the Issue tracker for Bouncy Castle http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-217 it shows the patches, the patching and that some testing has been performed by the original submitter.

This is relatively recent change, but you can find the latest release version from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html and on that page is a link to the betas which are at http://downloads.bouncycastle.org/betas/

The current beta is 147b14 so that should contain what you need.

There is probably limited documentation - but with BouncyCastle the best place to start is to look at the test code which will normally show how the implementation should be used.

Comment: Thanks I hope this implementation does what I need

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I've not used it directly, but the Bouncy Castle mailing list (dev-crypto) is a good place to get assistance.

Answer (score -1):

There is a European Community Initiative in GitHub: https://github.com/nonorganic/dssnet

Comment: This is .net. Question is old but is asking for java